# Incompatible Object Types - Java

Tags: java, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I'm trying to implement a small Java program which shows how process scheduling works. My current code is below. The issue I'm having is with the static method `CPU.executeInstructions(Process process)` and `firstComeFirstServed()` from the `ProcessScheduler` class. My program currently won't compile as it gives

```
incompatible type error: Object can not be converted to Process
```

from within `firstComeFirstServed()`.

I've managed to make it compile by changing `executeInstructions()` argument from `Process process` to `Object process`, but as far as I can see there is nothing wrong with the previous method signature. I've thrown a couple of `System.out.println()` calls in around the program to print the class to the screen, which confirms that the object being operated on is a `Process` object. Can somebody explain what is going on here? What am I missing/not understanding?

```
package processes;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import processes.ProcessScheduler.Algorithm;

public class ProcessManager {
    private static Thread psThread;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create process table
        ProcessTable pt;
        //System.out.println("1 " + pt.getClass());
        // Creat Process Scheduling Thread.
        psThread = new Thread(new ProcessScheduler(Algorithm.FIRST_COME_FIRST_SERVE, pt = new ProcessTable()));
        System.out.println("2 " + pt.getClass());
        // Start Thread
        psThread.start();
        System.out.println("3 " + pt.getClass());
        try {
            // Add Process' to table
            String[] instrucSet = {"sout","name"};
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                pt.add(new Process(ProcessTable.processCounter, i + 1, 10 - i, instrucSet));
            }
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                pt.add(new Process(ProcessTable.processCounter, i + 1, 10 - i, instrucSet));
            }
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            ProcessScheduler.run = false;

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ProcessManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}



package processes;

public class Process {
    private int quanta, priority, pID;
    private String [] instructions;


    /**
     * Constructor for Process class.
     * @param p_id process id
     * @param instruction_set Instructions to be processed by the CPU.
     * @param quanta Represents length of time (known or estimated) taken to execute process
     */
    public Process(int p_id, int quanta, String instruction_set[]){
        // Initialise instance variables
        this.pID = p_id;
        this.quanta = quanta;
        this.instructions = instruction_set;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for Process class.
     * @param quanta Represents length of time (known or estimated) taken to execute process
     * @param priority Represents the priority of the process, from 1 to infinity with 1 having highest priority.
     * @param instruction_set Instructions to be processed by the CPU.
     */
    public Process(int p_id,int quanta, int priority, String instruction_set[]){
        // Initialise instance variables
        this.pID = p_id;
        this.quanta = quanta;
        this.priority = priority;
        this.instructions = instruction_set;
    }

    /**
     * @return Returns length of process, which may either be a known or estimated quantity.
     */
    public int getQuanta() {
        return quanta;
    }

    /**
     * @return Returns process priority level.
     */
    public int getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    /**
     * @return Returns process id, a unique value generated when the process is accepted onto the process table.
     */
    public int getpID() {
        return pID;
    }

    /**
     * @return Returns an array holding the instructions to be processed for this process.
     */
    public String[] getInstructions() {
        return instructions;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Process ID: " + this.getpID() + ". Quanta: " + this.getQuanta() + ". Priority: " + this.getPriority();
    }

}


package processes;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author dave
 */
public class ProcessTable extends ArrayList {

    // P_id counter;
    public static int processCounter = 0;

    public ProcessTable(){
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Adds the specified process to the collection and increments the processCounter
     * @param aProcess The process to be added to the Process Table.
     * @return Returns true if successfully added.
     */
    public boolean add(Process aProcess){
        boolean sucessful = super.add(aProcess);
        if(sucessful)
            processCounter++;
        return sucessful;
    }

    /**
     * Prints the process table to console.
     */
    public void displayProcessTable(){

        for(int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(this.get(i).toString());
        }
    }
}


package processes;

/**
 *
 * @author dave
 */
public final class CPU {

    private CPU(){

    }

    public static void executeInstructions(Process process){
        System.out.println(process.toString());        
    }

}


package processes;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


/**
 *
 * @author dave
 */
public class ProcessScheduler implements Runnable {    
    public static boolean run;
    // The algorithm to be used.
    private String alg;
    // To hold reference to a Proces Table.
    public static ProcessTable pt;

    // Class constants for scheduling algorithm type. Used in class constructor.
    // Enum for 
    public enum Algorithm {FIRST_COME_FIRST_SERVE, SHORTEST_JOB_FIRST, ROUND_ROBIN, PRIORITY_QUEUE};  

    /**
     * @param scheduling_algorithm Sets the scheduling algorithm to be used when
     * @param process_table A Process Table instant that Process will be added to.
     * passing jobs to the CPU for execution.
     */
    public ProcessScheduler(Algorithm scheduling_algorithm, ProcessTable process_table){
        //System.out.println("4 " + pt.getClass());
        // Create reference Process Table
        //pt = new ProcessTable();
        pt = process_table;
        System.out.println("5 " + pt.getClass());
        // Start scheduling based on algorithm represented by enum in constructor arg.
        switch(scheduling_algorithm){
            case FIRST_COME_FIRST_SERVE:
                alg = "fcfs";
                break;
            case SHORTEST_JOB_FIRST:
                alg = "sjf";
                break;
            case ROUND_ROBIN:
                alg = "rr";
            case PRIORITY_QUEUE:
                alg = "pq";
            default:
                alg = "pq";
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Start Scheduling processes to the CPU
     */
    public void run() {        
        //boolean run = true;
        int sleepTime = 1000;
        //Display algorithm to screen
        try {
            run = true;
            while(run){
                if(!pt.isEmpty()){
                    switch (alg) {
                        case "fcfs":
                            System.out.println("6 " + pt.getClass());
                            firstComeFirstServed();
                            break;
                        case "sjf":
                            shortestJobFirst();
                            break;
                        case "rr":
                            roundRobin();
                            break;
                        case "pq":
                            priorityQueue();
                            break;
                    }
                } else {
                    Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ProcessScheduler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Executes all processes in Process Table on a First Come First Served 
     * basis (the order in which they were added to the collection).
     */
    private void firstComeFirstServed(){
        System.out.println("7 " + pt.getClass());
        for(int i = 0; i < pt.size(); i++){
            CPU.executeInstructions(pt.get(i));
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ProcessScheduler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    private void shortestJobFirst(){
        System.out.println("in SJF");
    }
    private void roundRobin(){
        System.out.println("in RR");
    }
    private void priorityQueue(){
        System.out.println("in PQ");
    }

}
```

Comment: Pay attention to the warnings you're getting about generics.

Comment: @chrylis as far as i can see (and have just checked again), NetBeans isn't showing any warnings about generics, only about params missing from comments. Could this have something to do with my issue?

Comment: I'm not sure; I'm not a fan of NetBeans. You're using enums, which weren't introduced until Java 5 along with generics, but you're extending `ArrayList` without specifying the type, which is your immediate problem. Your `add` method is also questionable; use `@Override`.

Comment: @chrylis Thanks, I added the type specification to the extension of ArrayList and problem solved. No generics warnign from NetBeans = time try Eclipse! Post an answer and I'll accept it as solved. Cheers.

Comment: It's `javac` that prints the generics warnings, not Netbeans. You need to enable compiler warnings in the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have noted, `ProcessTable` should extend `ArrayList<Process>`. However there isn't much reason for the `ProcessTable` class to exist at all. All is does is provide an incorrectly implemented counter (should not be static) and a display method. I would remove it and just use `ArrayList<Process>`.

Comment: Thanks. I've extended ArrayList as I'm planning on putting more functionality into the class. Quick question, why shouldn't the counter be a static variable? Is it because there is only ever going to be one instance of the ProcessTable class, and therefore I don't have to worry about multiple instances holding different values (potentially causing duplicate ID's)?

Comment: It can't be static *unless* there is only ever going to be one instance, and even then it isn't at all necessary. So why run the risk? Don't make things `static` unless you know exactly why you're doing it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your ProcessTable class that extends ArrayList is not generic.
You can start by modifying it with

```
public class ProcessTable<E> extends ArrayList<E> {
```

Then when you instantiate it, you can specify the class type ProcessTable will hold inside

`ProcessTable<Process> pt;`

That way the compiler will know which class will return the `pt.get(i)` call.

if not, it will treat it as Object.

EDIT:
As @EJP noted, being more specific to your problem you probably want to extend ArrayList with the specific class type it will work with

```
public class ProcessTable extends ArrayList<Process>
```

Comment: More probably he should write `public class ProcessTable extends ArrayList<Process>`.

Comment: Yeah, being more problem specific, you're right. @EJP

Answer (score 2):

Your ProcessTable definition should be like this:

```
public static class ProcessTable extends ArrayList<Process>
```